# How to split strings from streams using Java

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a huge `.txt` file and format is like below:

```
29 clueweb12-1500wb-39-00001
19 clueweb12-1500wb-39-00002
20 clueweb12-1500wb-39-00003
```

I need to read that file line by line and separate two parts. The first part has scores`(29,19,20)` and the second part is docIds (`clueweb12-1500wb-39-00001`). I read to `txt` file line by line by using stream but how can i put these two parts in a `String`?

```
Stream<String> lines = File.lines(Paths.get("path-to-file");
lines.forEach(s -> s.split(" "));
```

`

Comment: What should be the output?

Comment: Actually, ı put these part into a Map<Integer ,List<String> to do this i need to two of them separately

Answer (score 2):

To make the code clearer, you could use simple `foreach` loop:

```
Stream<String> lines = File.lines(Paths.get("path-to-file");
lines.forEach(s -> s.split(" "));

/**
* Takes a stream, splits group by first part of the string:
*/
public Map<Integer, List<String>> split(Stream<String> a) {

    Map<Integer, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();

    a.forEach(s -> {
        String[] pair = s.split(" ");

        Integer key = Integer.valueOf(pair[0]);
        String value = pair[1];

        // as 4castle suggested - to avoid unnecessary computation
        result.computeIfAbsent(key, key -> new ArrayList<>());

        result.get(key).add(value);
    });

    return result;
}
```

Or you can map your input directly in the stream processing:

```
a.map(s -> s.split(" "))
 .forEach(pair -> {
     Integer key = Integer.valueOf(pair[0]);
     String value = pair[1];

     result.putIfAbsent(key, new ArrayList<>());    
     result.get(key).add(value);
 });
```

Comment: In order to avoid creating a `new ArrayList<>()` on the iterations where it's not needed, you can use `result.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>())`

Comment: @4castle yes, absolutely right! I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Java streams way, I believe, is:

```
    Map<Integer, List<String>> parts = lines.map(s -> s.split(" "))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(splitLine -> Integer.valueOf(splitLine[0]),
                    Collectors.mapping(splitLine -> splitLine[1], Collectors.toList())));
```

This gives you the following map:

```
{19=[clueweb12-1500wb-39-00002], 20=[clueweb12-1500wb-39-00003], 29=[clueweb12-1500wb-39-00001]}
```

Its `toString` method doesn’t give you the most readable output, but I believe it’s the map you asked for. For now there is only one string in each list, but if multiple lines have the same score, there will be more.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) with a downstream collector which gets the second part of the split line before collecting to a list.

```
Map<Integer, List<String> table =
    Files.lines(Paths.get("path-to-file"))
         .map(line -> line.split(" ", 2))
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
             parts -> Integer.valueOf(parts[0]),
             Collectors.mapping(parts -> parts[1], Collectors.toList())
         ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get in the HashMap like this : 
Read the file and split it using String Split function and save in into the HashMap key value pair.

```
public static HashMap<Integer, String>  readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    try {
        HashMap<Integer, String> fileData = new HashMap<>(); 
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            String[] lineData = line.split(" ");
            System.out.println(lineData[0]+" "+lineData[1]);
            fileData.put(Integer.valueOf(lineData[0]), lineData[1]);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        return fileData;
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
}
```